# Count the 1 and 0 by group in Pig

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

How to count how many 1 and 0 here for each type of events? I'm doing all this in pig and there's only 1 and 0 in the second field. 
The data looks like this:

```
(pageLoad,1)
(pageLoad,0)
(pageLoad,1) 
(appLaunch,1)
(appLaunch,0)
(otherEvent,1) 
(otherEvent,0)
(event,1)
(event,1)
(event,0)
(somethingelse,0)
```

The output will be something like this

```
pageLoad 1:234 0:2359
appLaunch 1:54 0:111
event 1:345 0:0
```

or

```
type 1 0 
pageLoad 21 345
appLaunch 0 123
event 234 12
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input :**

```
pageLoad,1
pageLoad,0
pageLoad,1 
appLaunch,1
appLaunch,0
otherEvent,1 
otherEvent,0
event,1
event,1
event,0
somethingelse,0
```

**Pig Script :**

```
A = LOAD 'input.csv'  USING  PigStorage(',') AS (event_type:chararray,status:int);
B = GROUP A BY event_type;
req = FOREACH B {
    event_type_1 = FILTER A BY status==1;
    event_type_0 = FILTER A BY status==0;
    GENERATE group AS event_type, COUNT(event_type_1) AS event_type_1_count, COUNT(event_type_0) AS event_type_0_count;
};  
DUMP req;
```

**Output :**

```
(event,2,1)
(pageLoad,2,1)
(appLaunch,1,1)
(otherEvent,1,1)
(somethingelse,0,1)
```